# Find $|z|$ if the given expression is purely imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find $|z|$  if $\dfrac{z-2}{z+2}$ is entirely imaginary.

I know that if a number is purely imaginary, then $z-\overline{z}=2i$(some integer).

Comment: Your statement, "*If a number is purely imaginary, then $z-\overline{z}=2i\cdot(\text{some integer})$*" is false since it need not be an integer multiple of $2i$.  Furthermore, the hypothesis is irrelevant since this is true for arbitrary complex numbers as well.  $z-\overline{z}$ is *always* purely imaginary, so $z-\overline{z}$ being imaginary doesn't tell us anything about whether or not $z$ is.

Comment: z isn't purely imaginary.  (z-2)/(z + 2) is.

Comment: If z = a + bi then $(z - 2)/(z + 2) = ((a-2) + bi)/((a + 2) + bi = ((a-2)+bi)((a+2) - bi)/((a+2)+bi)((a+2)-bi) =[ (a^2 - 4) + b^2 +\{(a+2)b - (a-2)b\}i]/[(a + 2)^2 + b^2$  This is purely imaginary iff $(a^2 - 4) + b^2 = 0$ ie if $a^2 + b^2 = 4$ so $|z|^2 = 4$ so |z| = 2.

Answer (score 2):

One may write
$$
\frac{z-2}{z+2}=\frac{(z-2)(\bar{z}+2)}{(z+2)(\bar{z}+2)}=\frac{|z|^2-4+4i\:\Im z}{|z+2|^2}
$$ and this is purely imaginery iff $|z|^2-4=0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sure! Thanks!

Comment: Conjugate of (z-2)÷(z+2) will be? I'm sorry, I've just started this chapter and I don't know much about it

Comment: @VankshuBansal $\overline{x\cdot y} = \overline{x}\cdot \overline{y}$, also $\overline{(\frac{1}{x})}=\frac{1}{\overline{x}}$ so you can simply conjugate the numerator and the denominator simultaneously to find the conjugate of that.  It is irrelevant to the problem however.

Comment: @JMoravitz can you explain me the answer briefly pls? I'm not getting it. I'm extremely new to complex numbers

Comment: @Vankshu Bansal Do you understand the first equality in my answer?

Comment: Yes, but after that, I can't figure out what's happening

Comment: @vakanshu olivier multiplied the original expression by one.  The trick was how to write the number one, in this case as a conveniently chosen fraction involving z.  From there things simplified nicely.  As the denominator is purely real, the number will be imaginary only if the real part of the numerator is zero.

Comment: Then we have $(z-2)(\bar{z}+2)=z\bar{z}+2(z-\bar{z})-4=|z|^2-4+4i\:\Im z$, since  $z-\bar{z}=2i\:\Im z$.

Comment: Got you, thanks !!